# determine the probability that the winner was never behind at any point in the counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> (HMMT 2000 Power #8). An election takes place between two candidates. Candidate A wins by a vote of 1032 to 971. If the votes are counted one at a time and in a random order, determine the probability that the winner was never behind at any point in the counting.

> Below is my attempt at solving the problem. I am unable to find $P(Z_2)$, which is defined near the end and is required for me to solve this problem.

We should be able to generalize the problem by replacing $1032$ with $M$ and $971$ with N, so we do so. We can define the sample space to be the set of sequences consisting of the letters A and B and of length $M+N$, where each sequence has a $\dfrac{1}{{M+N\choose M}}$ chance of occurring, since there must be M A's. For $M\ge N > 0,$ let $P_{M,N}$ be the probability that in an election with two candidates A and B who had $M$ and $N$ votes respectively at the end, the candidate with M votes was never behind the candidate with N votes.  For $M=3,N=2$, we have the following sequences: $AAABB*,AABAB*,ABAAB*,BAAAB,AABBA*,ABABA*,BAABA,ABBAA,BABAA,BBAAA.$ Only the sequences marked with a * at the end are valid. So the probability in this case is $1/2.$ For $M=2,N=1$, we have the sequences $AAB*,ABA*,BAA$, giving a probability of $2/3$.

I initially thought of finding the probability that there exists a time when the winner was actually behind at some point in the counting, and then taking the complement of this probability. Note that if A is not always ahead of B (i.e. if not every prefix of the final sequence of length $M+N$ has more As than Bs), then if A was behind B at some point, A must have been behind B by exactly one at some point. Indeed, we may define the function $f$ on a sequence s of As and Bs of length $M+N$ so that $f_s(x)$ is defined to be the number of As minus the number of Bs in the prefix of s of length x. Then for $x<M+N, f_s(x+1) = f_s(x)\pm 1$, depending on whether the $x+1$th element is an A or a B. Also, $f_s(M+N) \ge 0$ since we're assuming $M\ge N$. So if A was behind B at some point, there is some $x$ with $f_s(x) < 0$. Hence there must exist some $y \ge x$ with $f_s(y) = -1$, as otherwise if we let $t$ be maximum with $f_s(t) < -1$, then $f_s(t+1) > -1,$ contradicting the fact that $|f_s(t)-f_s(t+1)|=1$. Thus we have just proven the following claim:

Claim 1: If A was behind B at some point, then there must exist some $n\ge 0$ so that at some point there were exactly $2n+1$ votes, $n+1$ of which were for B and the rest of which were for A.

The following claim will also be useful:

Claim 2: for $M\ge N>0$, let $B_{M,N}$ be the same as $P_{M,N}$, except define it to be the probability of getting a tie (i.e. a prefix of the final sequence with the same number of As and Bs). Then $B_{M,N} = \dfrac{2N}{M+N}.$

Proof of claim 2: If a sequence first has a tie with $2n$ letters where $n\ge 1$ and $n\leq b$, we may swap the As and Bs to obtain a bijection between sequences with a tie beginning with A and sequences with a tie beginning with B. But every sequence S beginning with B must have a tie since $f_S(1) = -1$ and $f_S(M+N)\ge 0$. Hence the probability of getting a tie is just twice the probability of starting with B, or $\dfrac{2N}{M+N}.$

Consider an arbitrary sequence $S$ of $M$ As and N Bs. Assume A was behind B at some point and let $n\ge 0$ be minimal so that there is some prefix P of S with $n+1$ Bs and n As. Then for prefixes of length $x<2n+1,$ we must have $f(x)\ge 0$. So $n+1 \leq N \leq M.$ If S starts with B, then $n=0$, and there is a $\dfrac{N}{M+N}$ chance of that occurring. So suppose S starts with A. However, simply swapping As and Bs, is NOT enough to define a bijection between set of the sequences where A was behind B at some point and the set of sequences where B was behind A at some point, since we can have a prefix with N Bs and $N+1$ As. Let $Z_1$ be the set of sequences so that S where B was behind A at some point and the smallest $n$ so that there is some prefix P of S with $n$ Bs and $n+1$ As is at most $N-1$. We can however define a bijection between the set of sequences where A was behind B at some point and $Z_1$. Now obviously, either A was behind B at some point, B was behind A at some point, or there is a tie. Denote the corresponding sets of sequences by $X,Y,Z$ and let $Z_2 = Z\backslash Z_1$. Obviously if $M=N,Z_2=\emptyset$ so suppose $M>N$. To find $Z_2$, we need to find the number of sequences of length $M+N$ so that  Then $P(Y) = P(Z_1)$. We want to find $P(Z_2)$. Any sequence S in $Z_2$ must begin with a $B$, so that $f_S(1) = -1$ and hence must have a tie at some point (since $f_S(M+N) >0$ under our assumptions).

> But the above only shows that $P(Z_2)\leq 1/2 P(X)$ and we need an exact formula for $P(Z_2)$, which turns out to be similar to $P_{M,N}$.

Then by claim 2 above, $P(X) = 2N/(M+N)$ and $P(X) + P(Y) + P(Z) = 1\Rightarrow 2N/(M+N) + 2P(Y) + P(Z_2) = 1\Rightarrow P(Y) = \dfrac{1}2 (1- P(Z_2) - 2N/(M+N)).$

Alternatively, I'm not sure if it's possible to define a recurrence relation for $P_{M,N}$.

Comment: This is essentially [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) though that the simple version of that finds the probability of always being strictly ahead and you want the possibilities of ties during the count

Comment: @Henry are you saying that the desired probability can be found easily using Bertrand's Ballot Theorem? I can't see why that would be true, since all desired sequences are a subset of the set of sequences with at least one tie. Basically A is always ahead of B or A ties with B.

Comment: The same article has a section entitled [Variant:_ties_allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3171130/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1479412/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/470627/